# Hamburger button not showing up whith Shell default Template

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, .net-standard-2.0

I am trying to show 3bar/hamburger on shell layout of xamarin .net standard .When i create default shell project hamburger button is not display and when i swipe the screen right to left flyout design will comes but my issues is i want to display the hambuger button ,so when i click on button flyout manu/item layout comes.[image: here is uploaded the image please see in url i want to display hamburger button before browser tital]

flyout manu image is when i swipe window right to left
[image]

Comment: What's your Xamarin.Forms version,i could not reproduce the issue in the latest version.

Comment: i am using Xamarin version   16.4.000.307 (d16-4@e031886)

Comment: Are you using MasterDetailPage ? If so there must be something wrong with your code.

Comment: Couldn't reproduce.
The hamburger menu shows up in the shell app I created

Comment: @FarazSaleem i mean the nugetpackage Xamarin.Forms version.

Comment: Xamarin.form version is 4.3.0.908675

Comment: I still could not reproduce your issue with version 4.3.0.908675,try to update to the latest version and run it